# Can I detect whether a browser's Bookmarks toolbar is enabled with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

I have a bookmarklet, and my users are consistently clicking it instead of dragging it to their bookmarks bar first.  I'd like to add an animation which would run in response to a click on the bookmarklet, say "Drag me to your bookmarks bar!" and show a nifty arrow pointing at the bar.

But that only makes sense if the browser's bookmarks bar is actually visible.  Can I detect whether the bookmarks bar is visible using JavaScript?

Comment: That's going to be browser specific and there are no standards for that as far as I know.  rather, you might consider just using a fancy little tooltip on mouseover saying drag me to your bookmarks bar.

Comment: Although I applaud the sentiment, I'd imagine most users of bookmarklets have their bookmarks bar turned on :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For security reasons (among others), no - this is not possible with JavaScript.

Even if a browser chose to make this information accessible to the client, it would not be a standard implementation (supported across multiple browsers).

Answer (score 1):

Put a div inside the link that holds a message when the user clicks on it use CSS to show the message. `#bookmarklet:active #message{display:block;}`  You will need some javascript to return false on the click event.

Comment: Or you could just have a global script that runs and searches for links with an `href` value that starts with `javascript:`, and attach said event handler.

Comment: @Nightfirecat You could, but you would want to attach a class name not an just an event handler.

Comment: Class name, definitely; and I'll probably keep the message completely separate from the link and handle the whole thing via JavaScript to allow for fancier animation.

Comment: @Will Martin Of course, with CSS3 you can get some pretty fancy animations though, to bad their not implemented completely yet.