# Website is redirecting to google as soon I open devtools

Tags: javascript, console, google-chrome-devtools, eval, devtools

I would like to check Network > Media > Initiator of a video, however, the website does not let me open dev tools, if I do, I get redirected within a second to google. The code responsible for this I have found in the source. They are protecting the video resources from downloading I suppose.

```
var element = new Image;
var devtoolsOpen = false;
element.__defineGetter__("id", function() {
devtoolsOpen = true; // This only executes when devtools is open.
window.location.href = "google";
});
setInterval(function() {
devtoolsOpen = false;
console.log(element);
}, 1000);
```

I have managed to override this, (disabling JS did not work, setting Image and element to null did not work either), but I had to be pretty creative, I injected some code via self made chrome extension, I simply set that interval above to 1000000. Pressing F8 or Ctrl+\ very fast after opening dev tools will expose the true server location as well(but not the mp4 resources)

However, I am curious as to how the above code works, step by step:

- Why new Image on the first line? That variable is passed to console log further down and logs "img" with an error (TypeError: Cannot read property 'requestContent' of undefined)
- Second line "devtoolsOpen" this makes sense but how is this state checked later?
- 3rd line "**defineGetter**" is probably just the old version of defineProperty(), but when is the function called, what is the trigger(line 4) ? And the redirect to google happens consistently.

And why does the setInterval callback log ${element}? Why is that element an image?

I do not think all the answers can be given from the above snippet, there is a massive eval() call a line above in the source.

```
eval(function(p,a,c,k,e,d){e=function(c){return(c<a?'':e(parseInt(c/a)))+((c=c%a)>35?String.fromCharCode(c+29):c.toString(36))};if(!''.replace(/^/,String)){while(c--){d[e(c)]=k[c]||e(c)}k=[function(e){return d[e]}];e=function(){return'\\w+'};c=1};while(c--){if(k[c]){p=p.replace(new RegExp('\\b'+e(c)+'\\b','g'),k[c])}}return p}('z 26=\'{"27":"28+29+2a\\/2b\\/2c\\/25+j+2d\\/2f+2g+2h\\/2i\\/2j\\/2k+2l+2e+23\\/1U\\/22+1N\\/b+1O+1P+1Q+1R\\/1S\\/1M\\/1T\\/1V+1W+1X\\/1Y+1Z\\/20+21\\/2m\\/\\/24+2n\\/2H\\/2J\\/2K\\/2L+2\\/2M\\/2N+2O\\/2P+2I\\/2Q+2S+2T\\/2U+2V+2W+2X+2Y\\/2R+2G\\/2x\\/2F+2q\\/2r\\/2s\\/2t+2u\\/2v+2p+1K\\/2y\\/2z+2A\\/2B\\/T+2C\\/2D+2E\\/2o+1L+1s\\/1J\\/O\\/P\\/Q\\/R+S+U+V\\/K+W\\/Y\\/10\\/11\\/12+13\\/14+15+X\\/L\\/C\\/J\\/x+w\\/v\\/u\\/t+q+y+r\\/A+B+E+F+G+H\\/I\\/16+M\\/18+1r\\/\\/1t\\/1u\\/1v+1w\\/1x\\/1y+1z+17\\/1A+1C+k\\/1D\\/1E+1F+1G\\/1H+1I\\/1B+1q\\/1h\\/1p+1a\\/1b\\/1c\\/1d+1e+1f+19\\/1g+1i\\/1j+\\/1k+1l\\/1m\\/1n+1o+2Z\\/2w+31+3m+4B+4C+4D+4E+4F+30\\/4G\\/4A+4H+4J\\/\\/4K+4L+4M+4N\\/4O+4P\\/D+4I\\/4y\\/4p\\/4x+4i+4j+4k\\/4l+4m+4n+4h\\/4o+4q\\/4r\\/4s+4t+4u\\/4v\\/+4R\\/4Q+4z+4S+5c\\/5d+5e+5f\\/5g+5h\\/5i+5k\\/5b+5l\\/5m\\/N\\/5n+5o\\/5j+5a+51+58+59\\/4U+4V\\/d\\/4W+4X+4Y+4Z+4T\\/50+52+53\\/54\\/55\\/56\\/57+4w\\/4g\\/3D\\/4e+4f+3n\\/3o\\/3p\\/3q\\/3r\\/3l\\/3s\\/\\/3u+3v\\/3w++3x+3y\\/3z+3A\\/3t+3j+3a+3i\\/33+34+35+36\\/37+38+32\\/39+3b\\/3c\\/3d\\/3e+3f+3g\\/3h+3B+3k+3C+3W\\/3Y+3Z+40+41+42+43\\/44\\/3X+45\\/47\\/48\\/49\\/4a\\/4b+4c\\/4d\\/46+3V\\/3M\\/3U\\/3F\\/3G\\/3H\\/3I\\/3J\\/3K+3E==","3L":"3N","s":"3O"}\';[\'g.h\']["\\i\\7\\e\\3\\5\\0"]["\\6\\4\\9\\8\\3\\0\\c\\6\\3\\4\\0"](\'\\0\\5\\3\\c\\0\\9 \\3\\m\\7\\8\')()[\'\\o\\4\\6\\c\\l\\5\\9\\3\'][\'\\3P\\0\\7\\3\\5\'](([\'g.h\']+[])["\\6\\4\\9\\8\\3\\0\\c\\6\\3\\4\\0"][\'\\i\\0\\4\\l\\n\\m\\p\\0\\n\\4\\o\\5\'][\'\\p\\f\\f\\e\\3Q\'](3R,\'3S\'[\'\\8\\f\\e\\7\\3\'](/[a-3T-Z]{1,}/)))',62,335,'x72|||x74|x6f|x65|x63|x69|x73|x6e|||x75||x6c|x70|sojson|v4|x66|||x6d|x68|x43|x64|x61|6DU98R0RzKURCnNtGRBypKIvNvSIuPX7ed1lq|CWnRnF90dTyfqHFE7I||QIxZGqgLMpqz2jLpC7f7rS0K6|wbNbaWLpJ6vKDn|Qw5N|0sVbuuED2sSvfQpbdGcoIJQDRHX66fT7WJzReJIsHl8fvXaWb1hrfGiR6ntvk3QJlczot56euty0GJjbZtzIliw7svbrEAyXlHbsGdGeBR7BAHuzuA|qwTRlcr|KWtZTWSuqs47zXHoINfw1JwCEGaxw6b|var|EYlVJkD1IHM|4Yg28EplNYJUBDW|1lQb3JTiaVYmR8GdoTMY5IUotocg||tVtBTLlzgh8H5md3WA07Vy|8yshRUVmQcuwyDwU3kl3YC6iIhO5VC2wlJsZB3S6rxoyRcJfts7RVPCUhWlnlaUoqHLoyp|44cVN0I44A|CDkzqbKUYRG|RhLy3WlhqrROV4rRQeejVE0vB2bC3rgq21yGOHLhwa9Yq37|vITsSl4sldh6wDWLFYAe43|nV|V5L1LgoWL0|GRHebO2AXkxrtzDo4hHy6miabXGxnEhJsZSppTGdtSFWSJ0fYrz1JwbnbdqDvwtU8||HGz4AJ9uxdGPQnbUi3Vvopil8QE5lQdY4rRPe|dUAw1AxAQVdB37m2wecWGUXM0V9T|EvCgOtzGc6wb|K5J37vvl2xp2Mw|rB1k75O||pfw6o6h|jTb0gj5YKdzUrtK2N8HcfBkRjzC7oaJ6KclvFxcaALA6cHD|f0Fg9o2Gg8biDbmbVFFnioDmzLfkfzkco80oV8BGDcGkVy7xBH|Rd0GOZgS5PDCGcBmbMLEUw7Zqa681R6cHTfXTlJyv3H5oom9Ecf69tehcRhm2|O1OA6vWonF6UhV1eMvuNdLX9Pnpj6C3TlIFykJIrTXG6WawlOTRmebP3yB7ZDs6||6UeXlrJYxxfwu1iKAJMqqaSExc4KffaxAu6Byqk30P77wEme8sKv|I1JIVUsHcz79xKYC4XJxejUDf|6WnlUI12O5WLh6ErJBrEBLfJIcrWbmWL|D1RcyDQWrasmXu9J4rOou4Nw|cdMZrYcZgTCATjzJpZqlerYqm9m7d|ikw9xcK3o1SARTIkG|25qklfDpmhsEqPSXNPIfsK3VXyd4lQD5Dldtuzu4aA7e3Jegz7GcqyhMUArtoNyX8v|HR249x9yVfusJGyL|8S0G6BbMY2AXD2zQYH9McLC9OFa8CvtPXq2GwllgdjfoiF1AP|hjDMtONN|E05IUwnzDasK7b4ryP56AEB81OOD|ymgL|h6SSBIjRd7mafW1gJ4LnXFHJFEi3wNhoAk4yaZmhJixMAjXuCSnLMwt6473vuKmeyQjD5f3pzY2yvDyvPraKYuLmbSNRaytn9Ie94Xwm7ryaAoIWW7sKdIvnT6vYmz|RgfaAMs1TKu7Vg8TFpMmn|iYN1GEV8dXE1kgDZhIue2rgUztM4|PgxmcnyBob2c2Bub2ZKGKf9XQfyL4HCAocJQQqxH|ZzFEYUngz4YxNXorHzSIJ3pHCNzIL3aOrp2Fj2U3nBKojEAJL8qMAxcYA|kNqzvVBo3hiNszr2FW6U|eQYl7qO8enmqDu8Vm|kitg9VWce1MC4G3YIOczt|DpvLIUIg1|9QfVwK0DM60zcGhGOgESJk4AEY3cG4n8ZbHk|rIOgZoav7bEADm|XqpvffHPFrBeYgYqFszVRebO4aCEoGK6PeqZ8|hrC5|B12vUn|POx1hCU8j9Ftzt6JsLCAgmg9p3mJctmDobfEDmIOr|3TOloFqBwNGcwYW3xCIsWG4Pf2qW7ht|RrWLt|3iPDXDQobVUZ608DJP8uoVYchYuezGPPNT4KYMq|AKPQJmTS2yWckBeBr|20ynr4I0CA7i3oxucP2sr9gYt6n|7L6PkpixXaHpwu|d8OlSbJK6exqQYwywrk3SQGoMI09qtHv|0KnqvGd5U0Iup|vpnXUeoQHzxabkD|D8ibEtDC3Qpyn00cKDnpZOOgyD7s6VACDQjagts838m1EDusaDsmmnfrYtGimDzD4Ky3WnyjNv2k3RWHvB3|1rCYE|pMehkJubGfuhb6MRaZfqVWOyzBzlqY9tMpAbywBTgYq|ovr3ChqjCmFVl6wG9|ndua5xVWFAZuQoP0nuu7o2Z4cLgreucJ6tO6C8F6nv|xK5hwHAzCO941oOQHtAvGWbvdsanuOyyvws2BGEXZp9eAdqNufnZOoWEe|f6iSwipSBh3qFkd1tEEPDdE|54cvI7xvr67nTu0dJmnEWATeszSqon5LLo6GU9skQI8Csiie3V3e3LommwbOU6kFbZ0bu3oeFo2uOHAZkb5SCHcvXvC3IbrK7Y5ckTkjwoGuQUvv5Sgm9Biqh3pi7Am33amovjJv0wtuUJK5EnMh3wgkLiWOMsYpeYUa8TdiEJhPmaukXResyPfs|ow5Fr3CKHdX5at|3y7vMZDz5P6Ryfr1|0KPyidXuudGNtDGh9Sv6pRgC|VcEO0FMQUSt0bI4eqHipeez0hqW0HEgBuNoPddiL7BGRFMg|liiUQF8Xc6eEtKFIl1gJQ3Zqb76RbMmM40iTqvP0R3poUyCb|6k2Cw4EMQBnQWjjvsB4L3Q0h7iDqrEhvoBfrZ0QiHah|RQhJq2pcij1qpsIUzqFNAPmf|AxF6k|v3Hq581TnPsdZoCA6wPoiYGVeOVE6DPs5vUiE7vS8SmXl0FjQal|cEHB5IemCkAbKs3aTgmko7M4cAE4sV5rNn|XlGUz4jNFDt1qQj060YJ|NJueRxuLMtxOl36vnF2plIZl|ru04TCMoXoTZl4hIH9D4UTLsgGXo0a7aORSi8|3l3GD|QCDOMRh5RMS9TtbZp5JW49IbzHndT4lfo2cDDGgYHsVZQL|Z6Sbq1EBMCmg7sE6NLR1CqGYTYBYE7|dNbAFwUaDyNKe8rT|5ZRNsNlAHAHJk2kfG4IAx2rxp2myw2UzgwnuQdwNqHK9hCoXqyd4|Fd1SwHWNU8YA|8WgzbsqK7p7fEPZTuRmrNeO|m6ucLyLBcKkQvEzfJR1pV|4VywZOf8bx2ewOw3xd4XM6Fw6OQPnk2dTF2TuUuU9kQWL|YFFH5ButVMIfsFm|11vgjrQ5RCS13e|data|ct|7rwc2w61bsatcdoX3C2Ac7uDoUqQgH9A|4kdaDT66Go3C9NUZsmo3TLwRCWd7ZbD6Hcb8lFynwAaM|LUeegHvqDInLmJFqNwKOSgYE1O22tsz9gysYfR|tyfMMvnv2PdO1CeTmtGZ8J6YlMziWiUxZooXEb1icSdiONkDcYBjzHm9r|VEhEKx9C5nDznNWfImI|U60taC3H|qN8fOY4nvlU9DpjYWn5rm|C29gRAjKz1|e6P0rArYyWfrhniuTztZu2h065|N6V3SKR1u6fpIWVLqW0pfkCmA|tXD3kf|N7nfpn4ptdD2pWMS9UZSidWZGW7V7rngLvUxgzYmQoXHfXCFJsEDsJ9u5z0iseZcDHVtomgUidtteCWFuYXP0driBnzXaJhFfVOBnJqrcWrIVN|9j5C7HjCcUJt8zsinTdpmVud80Ge4a|4tAw0DUbjkCNstHR64HbljC6dpVV|noX6ROmyOFCQWirklcpT1ysUcBy6|xuJiO|UjGJFqif6plgXtNa2SVYFUs1iwqSufSt54EC|OQfOtk2gyscfY|6lzS4Y9DV1rgXdx5npAJ|C6NFJtZTexQidK1ZWouTC088FHvf9Vvmoi5Od5|0ARadHBl2rQ5qyR3rAU6QeLXxSs2yIDnhEPWJRqubu1eBbQxjU3|cAh40wJit|3jMCim4|bU7pFq0O0MWpYZPp1BPlCYFy2QaammMYvJlKPs3cOveI0RZ8TSJdtpCQ1WJEquR4|LQ7gnetzY|eSI67S5Tgm|o0GUPVFnIO6UNrIt02Oy8pfqkQqj7C|4nh81hNQ0z0OC3BfEmuGLkWe4zU8zAmpJjKJ6XCng4GmNSQJjm0ZgITAok9M6ntmrduuSuAKmEYQAMuxifIJkEr|WjS2M5Hc5FWfHiyqM|LUrN|wyjm1OmXyM9RQra8vVc3x0UT|gIU|4ZUbG21laBPkIDOC4kTG4D|sBgvkYua0CDn4OjvsQkpWNmo8|lGNrXSNxHwrJR24qLLwvnlkbdLexrUYS7|ncAF|wi06VG6xYTht0a4IfbyQUuiFMPee|qemn2sLXOtgbSEq4HiMbBC3uAHFLKtI0LYM|Xa3XU8eMSRto6IO0iyZ0BcFPdQluDr5wtt8UL9xaucINXMeaBjvdk5C5DuVWtPaw4yejIZUI7IWi0bxUGSawd2cqxpQOUy2uGxhBfH5Wyu7Qh7jFfVb|AzvrYkmN6PGLgUu6L9GQhofHTM1TART6CaQbqQ1MWbJAnYvBRoN6u6A8O3r|p1HwB5prhutauHzm5R1BpP1CICovG5t43RXC25EE|he4aL1kIVCtW2pKxYY5AYQ0HxYeSegf0pRokCg4ewxpTwpMl2NfL7otK|9sibrvYhq2a8WvgyKcO9XBv8e1Ot3WO|ZOYbcWX4dGsxyzb1BRNUDmWQFtudtkOC0SsKNQK0HKOvmyFGGJL4KUzd8ScOOqf4VlBgfDGthMPeIR0sPjzNeRMWq|UFM|mKICvtAdPcYg609H|YiV9tox|FA62rkEgZR|hfhmhszUvNDTArLncuLUSg|Hdt7NkjB7asBaO|h03olcWkmW10UHS3uP9T4SxHSAeap|f69LDHmbQeZsWP2mtrsJBRz5NIzgpN96jHeb2U8Vea7B4eIea0cM|96LCxQ7qIrmi7OcXllnMymVEoC75|lTPtaFxuvDyTbWpIEweRuXPKNUdX8mBeMqVGB5V6sW|QDtwQz8HoOFPbJmW6RpgwbF1zlN7lH|MAqe3zkV|m0GGS|ONZCrSgTgpXCNz0eeLpJE3Ttnsvq04VDqWZaEs85AlW2YlIIPGRJlsEG6oiAPw9onZYqSEISDOpAxT8nmD|Dl4nVDYqBu5MdrEaX6OOYcmvAEdsns3IaYaWkLKxbEP1eF6zSBvVFZY|Q0QZECJKl6MaWlJQvuAwNd7tc4purdTIGSc0HnIKGZyedmb4GVURmcz6uSgF9uU2Q3n1oXgnI0iuIA9kD0|U5B8pDadN|KZtIxid|KpzR7Z|vp3NumvkAy2udhHVfZrwxuJRfcvCu0HZ|SGdq8HvBOaPcKBDtRQ5MHNK|kU1ry31n56|DPs7fAUazbuaZqXrq|EsV|bV1|hw5ftFwvkmLtfqENtqESlKayw31jMYdX2DviqbvVdF5|klDZit4|O9anBrDf3P|YsuFbT|JQPh0lDUzR4JgBWoNpgGJCXeCBB4vcJzo|H3YIa5UfXvDlsuKT7SC3nyB6vdctpjOZKz6FJNiidenA36CEWru63XhOUnu98e3DGLKkqO0omjTCUzc2xK60Ck6g45aa7NTrsz|YAyYhAjyxloA1Ez4pn|15fgqglXXF4mBNRceS5PrRQDMWDfekxZ9Gr66T6BbI|UJB6z|NJ7YutL0lYD6sauEObvIuZo9ZE4TJvFHPskVSAUYEQ4pN2mIRkXG|XqfvLyYmzqsCw1BWxPZtMwkziTZizdPiTGD9Uy8YnnR8KxioWnK2JmLSDDWAcpKXFI2EwpmDEkDPij19|mA4ur0ESBY|D4hWJXshUncoNLs4X9Ya|lIQ4jYtPFetHzwCq|TKjB3iO|hUpdOIdvacptdV|geD9db2nKyXYiFXZyily8HSEtbFjN5YXSYfkGERAQ3S7guI1UYE50hTFJEQExvs6NDzXPACrH|XZeOi|E5xGiN|TMOPOl|jN4TrQf6I1IU137WTZ9KqWMsNyAYZd|TpB73|gsMdUrDQpKuSd|r4lquC6f4PYnL8QgJLBdIL7gzqP1gDvCZ8iVVZ|vsnfErxcpkf3TvrmUZ3Su|ddKSYZgQHBqBZkfK9JwTVg1XfjymdL8GGAg|SE2oBBFgR|tXcA|ayinr28PMytTWwZm3oijhWkuRfSx80YZ8ubAZSqnLyB211S1B|MYcxXfCSV0|jGvXVUUk78FEh1URjRkT40ns0rp9yJHhL|wxGrAAahYVTWZicQINUSMIAo7EaAvV|iv|gDFPH8yyxrYvK4zyTWIqN|09769a8e8d4a7e1a9f8c51b5322394c8|fe98d7a64b2e4ffe|x77|x79|null|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|zA|Xu17VoXNa8QdaCbxbfF7oBjBwyQFZslOgbXCF68vI9kQePK4WpRaiJuBpXMKwk2KkT|AYTXaLsQqlWW9nhQJma6FTiKr7p7iS4KTlbMi2XuApi0mcXvF2hLOzGVvN|mxjJrLxf|8U7gnUclbInIE96hXn5UXLanHMS6m5DiGKcAGvX1T9xAuWH|J10eakS3iuVhfLRIPvA3|BjlzY5DA8Hl2el7xWgC|Ohafivxpj6orZofaVD7cVdCKkr|gH7iYbha962|TBVMi3D8VRajAy6zAntk0Hf4AkhHDXQEWv3j6FFyNDs1FaaAfsIT8Wjmk5BsgYWZtne5pEUUXNhZ|q1DUdPqcQwOP8E1CHb0uUq3cyCopFwGbdDO3QrxJsyRcdVuiuHpQLPpg|lRLIV4CF4x|jtnXs|qZ3wbWolIVBZcgp9NY5eOTF2bn4VPQcXY6YdfXe1kWnmrl2GirPsw470GJbTDLn4rsJI3YFczC3IwEQJQKvz86NoLEctZJ4JGhjfT5Dpoipl4|babz9JfL64Dj56hO9CJnyn1cKNuwnHFdTUsC1lmvFqg0EDFMEXKxGsFQABa4Z18zcGEf|B30FF7BLjI|CIBtbYEdtMWq11oi6XStxpVxyssxT3|tNKr7wQwl92mMKJD5cXLzJRgGh2YAzLCRfwQ5H26gQ|q9Ac95nyvBJb|nGnrYaam0hUripHUbzNXhSxxNAO2JtN0IIL0|7Jhc6Sgb46kyz|2rCk2QcAWOyZQ1aVkM8Xqx5JUuGQMZ2NBe1KTXr0icLIacZY861aGGzTe7YAEwvmbPOhWzgkjRUAQ3OvBOwd2fugkx3NXNOphzox0fsZENBKKwA712c1qoqeOeivs8Q|PRnIJ3enUO8jzy2aAue1h6xnuEHQfdZjZ|PPSd|x4V3V79G|EmEelhXufYQNbcQgwwY4II5zzm6LDZV7byQDkF9qPwNA5AJC1vCu9CoCfiEhvQajHrstHrMUUWRiMpF8TbXU10VLEvFdOWWYgzBvRtVTBIt1G|ztQ3qLKKO3HczTu08fJqtSqP0tpn719D|80kzBxRa5V4w0EbRBpUbB7adyrm4fVY76PDqlU|ny1ks5lytL2vM7wpLojDDmu1Yfyj|BBSPDmfiEz6V2kXhTdyvQ4LFn3C5ldKqGnNpV05DdcrSFZgXpmSK75c6UIz7ThOOtL5j9URMMwOobtQ|d6FeDvrkleZNs2udRXuheqznsz7VbDgfZEaq3ki|B3zjgWnmhC1NuogXiQdynYdt2|ZsHau7QxFn|QPwS131Oqwzz0w8AUkIAuNKzXv64SghNq0OLhWpCI3mFxa18sFhAAVC3Xv6KMXOLmfWqBt|aVS7R9VyzTL6azkCBF|OCDlVBVgENxZESEvFiWwziI1l|7y88mpnv3wvNCGvMqrQPvxEc1ST1iWN|kLa0ezpWJ8|GEBdHQsU7Gg2s61iHXaboGxRKueAIQ3FQPj4BakSEkFCUCyE8IKsRPqOnpdg|WDfwqwruzP0k|4VSig8HTKp7Ihp1zp7hfu7Tx5PPFApurcLE7LdzeWFX9ZmJxgPZgm9b6izcrpgpedEX48klGnvx|anQwNo48phdBL7IzwY7Jbm3k5QPCi9RxcjuHaa62OPRMfRFsmsI|nShVkNH92|5Syh72aNEewrYFMsj1cV2l6GVMo|WvCyy3U23ZktyomHPxU8vLZcWyHgRShDdDoC|A9ga40UMsb22Ijdbek2Lbc3jKSsD6qFd24KHnEYq1VrxJW0csUnhrbCUAsoHgtFts6BreDdWgE|ryprrdx2p3s8o00WcrXGzKKYFljz2xfHlDXxemt75f7EM00dZUeoEoN08eTfodL4qsUJWN4sbrNZFOG|EPWdQ4E5a4MvchUiiMJr7|R7FF7ZssvvQxcbkzvG6doPRvIdhtC|aiDyZmSBCneGvca|Cvr|4QHkx4VlLpZpG|y5RnDV8nXbhMPzwr9D5ZjdGlzDd0tBL85wLZ3r2HlxH4rbsPGgyCdtLBppw4L45TIC|jElfTZhR4gSbY1O8XSoFUtQ|Ad|0Q7s3PwBRZ2SYK5uJGd|ZxDRBXnSYL2u|EJLB8|xOG7uRD9Xq6rvjXjh144FWWat0QX76gBDMNJ9CvPCHwt70gTHwZWuQbn1raQbCVSPlEsFSn6|JNaZxrp76r0AOhjc4g30VCdH3WRRvTsSrlk1Ly7bZzeaSX6mdfMsuSxJVOM58Q3fwTlx3lMxZj7OYpxIIZU0qiyyjX3tdgreTRKbTAlaOFqfMBfBnCtwanjt8ysYNl69cHUw2cZqmtCAxksshykSVg|eAnqFlIKnecGowi8v|79y6t40UIxGspcQ1HcG|Z6c9X1OJFDSzdXzvUNjJdYBwz9NFe7ryW7sBmkFSfPc0S9NuuAmTwPCmEx|g3FwLz1fK3SfmswKzOESCHHBXEBBQfjQDMwkGRx|dzJYYiQD|KqzTZAy9Nq9gnWunb9L9jORavOCf3cRZGq0ebRmEhwtZdigpGZUELoP5tCjFVWArodBLDNuP9BIkKNU0N1ZgCsUvOFPiNNgfRrppl4|X3EAjlqsRslvrvb3xFuRPcxDRZuQCdVZIyzo|pJ902y1J4cx0pyWr93BaFN|4ERBsW|Av4HChDp7a2HF4DowWkViZC|QFSH2|y4mK9DzBUd9vJvtFlZbQrx0BjyDNCO4atnijB4JZ|vTt|xe0UfOkOu369pdBTt1Leow7ENiqXjFd37ixzuOipd3YcU3yeOakQXMfa0BrlrgWLbbK3sdoxxDHREvJf5P7r0q834qLPEF2H5NnrD03XOEAZEMTgsxJXOUehmEzDTLkNbyhSnlaDuYUUdikAjZc2o7N5W6EG2uRz5hfxRwUpBwHbvaP|eR0K4I|yBeNTdt7Ll09CTCirjvX6IJvMQIOOLBIlNXwOk35YEfSRZZ2aLq0e7v2Kp6whM6gAE70hdeY0lO|ozIsH0|kXBtqKmX48pIMQtiF3nmvoW7C2QaDPCyOD3RdH5hvWzeKuQr2J0|bF2y8S|ARxufVWbCwfcbZXeW|hZnEMDNIiERBthcSDUmGLzajp8XnWxWBR7cxmPGE5tJtM5c6|zBrVhZ7izWKxMm|vp5mpMlnpQ2BaaXK37eFo2HaV6TQIlGzWuQspiaP|M3Dfa1mFirGsVhN9l0ekrqcu9SbsLKEfV3W|XK1g6Ae4DPdjoPl6EHCYcmbAKBOQccUlJYfkqY3V|vjX0Y4waf3i9npuxdyQk9uCv0nCJusrQYa|lUv8ct7dyvF|uQZoktg0kGoc|Z4ZUrZr|KMKFPA6I341tFG2JM|8kGZmwHFCKYVB4vbsG1JRPvOHnKDkKzbUPt2kpLeHiEgEY|O4TcyY3TUsbByJYlwn3r3SIHJSf2AFGhCZ87EkNQInWm7rkErpA1w|GPpxor3F2YOWZID38d2RFVoL5G|A9ESII22wKY5rcrp9VaTsTqNtFPUmV'.split('|'),0,{}))
```

There is another horribly obfuscated and long line of JS but it looks just like a very long Switch Statement. So what is going on in this code?

I have found links with the same code (the comment gives it away, probably even the original author), [and explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42193700/), but it is not entirely satisfactory, I still do not fully understand.

Comment: `new Image` is document.createElement('img'). The getter is triggered by devtools itself when it opens. This code uses one of the known methods to detect devtools, see [Find out whether Chrome console is open](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30638226)

Comment: @wOxxOm I see in that link "    var element = document.createElement('any');, I get it now, it can be any element. And the function is called once dev tools are open as soon something is logged or every 1000ms. What is still a bit confusing, why is the id parameter passed to that function, when it is never defined. I see in the link you provided the user clears the console as well, clever:-)

Comment: `id` parameter is passed to define a getter for `id` property. The second parameter is the getter.