# How to detect Firefox Inspect Element is running or not?

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, firefox-developer-tools

I see a lot of ways to detect if Chrome Inspect Element is open or not.

Is there a way I can see if Firefox Inspect Element is open?

Here is a demo for Chrome https://blog.guya.net/chrome/dev_tools/.

Edit: The possible duplicate does not answer my problem. There are limited parameters that are available and will not work with Firefox.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect if console/devtools is open in all browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40153206/detect-if-console-devtools-is-open-in-all-browsers)

Comment: If you've found a way to make this work, then you've effectively found a minor security vulnerability: it now becomes possible for malware to hide itself from analysts with it. For this reason, Mozilla tries to keep this impossible, as do most other browser vendors.

Comment: @JosephSible Chrome and most Chromium web browsers are able to detect if the Inspect element is open or not. Opera, Brave, etc.

Comment: Yes, but it's not considered desirable, and once they have a good way to fix it, they will. They just happen to be losing the game of leapfrog at the moment.

Comment: @JosephSible Ah ok, So what you are saying is there is no possible way to detect if inspect element is open or not on Firefox. It is just a flaw in Chrome that people are using and can be patched at anytime. Just to make it clear.

Comment: I'm not saying there's no such flaw in Firefox, just that I don't know of one, and that I wouldn't expect one to last very long once it became well-known.

Comment: @JosephSible So, lets say Firefox is working properly no flaws/issues/bugs. Standard Firefox, is there no way to detect if inspect element is open or not?

Comment: In the ideal world, that's correct, it wouldn't be possible in Firefox. (It also wouldn't be possible in Chrome in the ideal world.)